# React Native Auth Session stopped working after Expo upgrade

Tags: typescript, react-native, oauth-2.0, expo, expo-auth-session

I was using Expo SDK 48 and my app was working fine with Google and Facebook authentication using a web browser based authentication scheme.

Working code:

```
type AuthResponse = AuthSession.AuthSessionResult & {
    params: {
        access_token?: string;
        error?: string;
    };
    type: string;
}
...

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: any) => {

/* Google */
    const signInWithGoogle = async (navigation: any) => {

        try {

            const SCOPE = encodeURI("email profile");
            const RESPONSE_TYPE = 'token';

            const authUrl = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=${GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&scope=${SCOPE}`;

            const { type, params } = await AuthSession.startAsync({ authUrl }) as AuthResponse;
            console.log("type ==>> " + type);
            console.log("params ==>> " + JSON.stringify(params));


            if (type === 'success') {

                checkGoogleUserInfo(params.access_token, navigation);

            } else {
                return;
            }

        } catch (error) {

            console.log("Error retrieving token data from Google ==>> ", error);
        }

    }


}
```

After Expo has been upgraded to SDK 50 and `expo-auth-session` to `5.4.0`, `AuthSession.startAsync()` stopped working.

I'm trying to use the new method from [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/) and follow [this example](https://gist.github.com/jdthorpe/aaa0d31a598f299a57e5c76535bf0690) but I'm getting following error while trying to fetch from the url on code below:

`Possible unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: <`

Not working code:

```
const endpoint = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
    const clientId: any = GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID;
    const redirectUri: any = REDIRECT_URI;
    const [discovery, setDiscovery] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {

        async function loadDiscovery() {

            // here is the issue causing promise rejection
            const getDiscovery = await fetchDiscoveryAsync(endpoint).then((discovery) => setDiscovery({ discovery })); 

           // nothing is displayed in console
            console.log("get getDiscovery >>>>>> " + JSON.stringify(getDiscovery)); 
        }

        loadDiscovery();
    }, []);



    const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest({ clientId, scopes: ['email', 'profile'], redirectUri }, discovery);

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log(discovery);

        if (!discovery) {
            console.log("no discovery");
            return;
        }

        if (response?.type === "error") {
            console.log("response type error: " + (response.params.error || "something went wrong"))
            return
        }

        if (!discovery || (response?.type !== "success")) {
            console.log("no discovery and no response type");
            return;
        }


        const code = response.params.code;
        if (!code) {
            console.log("no code");
            return;
        }


    }, [response, discovery]);
```

Is that still possible to use web browser based authentication with Google and Facebook?

*Edit*:

I finally got a `discovery` using `https://accounts.google.com` as an endpoint and the result is the json below. But my `response` is still `null`.

```
{
    "discovery": {
        "discoveryDocument": {
            "issuer": "https://accounts.google.com",
            "authorization_endpoint": 
            "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
            "device_authorization_endpoint": 
            "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/device/code",
            "token_endpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            "userinfo_endpoint": 
            "https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo",
            "revocation_endpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke",
            "jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs",
            "response_types_supported": [
                "code",
                "token",
                "id_token",
                "code token",
                "code id_token",
                "token id_token",
                "code token id_token",
                "none"
            ],
            "subject_types_supported": [
                "public"
            ],
            "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
                "RS256"
            ],
            "scopes_supported": [
                "openid",
                "email",
                "profile"
            ],
            "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
                "client_secret_post",
                "client_secret_basic"
            ],
            "claims_supported": [
                "aud",
                "email",
                "email_verified",
                "exp",
                "family_name",
                "given_name",
                "iat",
                "iss",
                "locale",
                "name",
                "picture",
                "sub"
            ],
            "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
                "plain",
                "S256"
            ],
            "grant_types_supported": [
                "authorization_code",
                "refresh_token",
                "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code",
                "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"
            ]
        },
        "authorizationEndpoint": 
        "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
        "tokenEndpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "revocationEndpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke",
        "userInfoEndpoint": 
        "https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo"
    }
}
```

How can I use this discovery document? I'm trying to get user email from Google after user enter his credentials as it was working before SDK changes.

Comment: Have you checked the raw response from the auth endpoint?  In all my dealings with APIs, `Unexpected character: <` usually means there was an error (usually a 4xx) of some sort and HTML was returned rather than JSON.  Google is notorious for it.

Comment: @KeithRusso I get no results in console if I try to check `discovery` from `await fetchDiscoveryAsync(endpoint).then(discovery => console.log(discovery));`. Can you tell me anything else that I can do?

Comment: @KeithRusso If I use microsoft endpoint I can get json as result. I think I must find another url from Google.

Comment: from this line `const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest({ clientId, scopes: ['email', 'profile'], redirectUri }, discovery);`, dump the `response` object after it's resolved and you should be able to  see what the raw response is.  And the URL you have in your example is correct based on Google's Auth documents. You should just be able to put the console.log() inside the second useEffect since you're watching for changes in response in your deps array

Comment: @KeithRusso Oh yes. I had already done a console.log() inside the second useEffect for `response` but it says it's `null` and `discovery` empty `{}`. I think it's due to promise rejection from Google's url.

Comment: @KeithRusso I edited my question with json returned from `request`.

Comment: @KeithRusso I edited my question again using discovery document I finally got from google. I don't know if it's the right discovery document but please check my edit session. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I finally find Google's discovery document link and using Uber authentication example, I can open the web browser authentication to enter Google's credentials:

```
const discovery = {
    authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
    tokenEndpoint: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
    revocationEndpoint: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke'
};


const AuthProvider = ({ children }: any) => {

     const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest({
        clientId,
        scopes: ['email', 'profile'],
        redirectUri,
        responseType: 'code',
    },
        discovery
    );

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log("request >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + JSON.stringify(request));
        console.log("response >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log("discovery >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + JSON.stringify(discovery));

    }, [response]);

    ...

    /* Google */
    const signInWithGoogle = async (navigation: any) => {

    try {

        promptAsync();
   
    } catch (error) {

       console.log("Error retrieving token data from Google ==>> ", error);
    }

}
```

I'm still facing an error after enter Google account login:

`Something went wrong trying to finish signing in`

but I think this should be discussed on another question.